# Automatically run js file script on mongodb to find and kill long running process of mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to continuous execute js file script on mongodb to find and kill long running process.

is it possible using cron ??

Comment: Do you have an handle to these processes, something like a pointer reference/object

Answer (score 0):

You should periodically execute db.killOp() in the context of the admin database.

In order to find out which processes are taking to long try using the following snippet.

The output contains opId.

As a  maximum accepted value for long-running processes 20 sec is used.

```
db.currentOp().inprog.forEach(

  function(op) {

    if(op.secs_running > 20) printjson(op);

  }

)
```